# AtUnit vs 'Junit,JMock and GUICE' by hand -?

Tags: junit, guice, jmock

How does AtUnit fare with respect to unit testing using DI and guice ?. Please share your experiences.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it works rather well and is very simple to use. In my case though, after a while, I decided to revert back to my old pattern of rarely using DI in unit tests, unless I'm testing something functional. I found that all the extras that AtUnit was providing were simply not being used in my situation.

In the cases where I do use Guice in tests, my unit test class extends `AbstractModule` and I do the Guice initialization etc manually in my `@Before` method. I suppose using AtUnit here would be pretty much the same with the exception that all my manual stuff would mostly disappear.